# Registration of IoC containers from several assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I try to understand what is best practice for registration of the objects into ioc container from different projects of one solution.

I have a solution with 4 projects and I saw a solution to create installers in each of the projects and then in one place call somtehing like this:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();
            var assemblyNames = new[] {"Dal", "Utils" };
            _container.Install(assemblyNames.Select(
                    x => (IWindsorInstaller)new AssemblyInstaller(Assembly.Load(x),
                        new InstallerFactory())).ToArray());
```

But also I saw a solution that in each project, there is a creation of container, and inside there is a registration of the objects that are relevant to this specific project.

My question is: what is the best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an example here : A web solution which consists of many projects : One Core project and many other which reference the core. All of them end up in different folders (or copied after build to the core/bin if you like). At start time we load them dynamically and then load the IWindsorInstallers from them. We load dlls like that :

```
public static void LoadMoules()
{            
    string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string binPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "bin");
    DirectoryInfo binFolder = new DirectoryInfo(binPath);
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> binFiles = binFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    Assembly[] domainAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    try
    {
        foreach (var binFile in binFiles)
        {
            AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(binFile.FullName);
            if (domainAssemblies.All(x => x.FullName != assemblyName.FullName))
            {
                Assembly.Load(assemblyName.FullName);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Loading {assemblyName.FullName}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       DynamicModuleLoaderEventSource.Log.FailedToLoadAssembly(exception.Message + exception.StackTrace);

    }    }
```

Then we get the registrations :

```
    try
    {
        foreach(Assembly moduleAssembly in installationModules)
        {
            // satellite proejct assemblies 

            Debug.WriteLine(moduleAssembly.FullName);
            ContainerRegisterEventSource.Log.InstallAssembly(moduleAssembly.FullName);
            container.Install(FromAssembly.Instance(moduleAssembly));
        }

        container.Install(FromAssembly.This()); // the core assembly
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        ContainerRegisterEventSource.Log.Exception(exception.Message + exception.StackTrace);
        Trace.WriteLine("SetupContainerForMigrations error : " + exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + exception.StackTrace);
    }
```

Doing it this way you will end up with one container with all the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Every executable project should have a container of its own as they are capable of running independently of other executable projects. Library project usually provide dependencies that are consumed in the executable project and as such it is the executable project's responsibility to register those dependencies in its container if it wants to make use of them with the library not having a container of its own.

Having multiple containers could cause a variety of issues for example, if a class is registered as a singleton (one reference shared among all consumers of the dependency) having multiple containers would result in multiple instance of the class being created (one in each container)

It could also cause issue if there are cross-project dependencies as the container would not be able to resolve a dependency registered in another container.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I create one project which contains most of my shared resources such as models, libraries and also IoC configuration which I use in the other projects. By configuring the IoC container from this project I'm saving myself some copy pasting. With this I keep the possibility to override the configuration from the project in which you're using this configuration.

In the end it's all about maintainability. If you use the same dependencies throughout all of your projects it'd be a pain in the arse to configure it time after time for each individual project.